# Determining if a recruiter is legit

Tags: recruitment, human-resources

A recruiter contacted me recently, but I'm wondering if this person/job is legit.

Reasons to believe the recruiter and job are real.

1. The email address matches the company she claims to be from
2. Her LinkedIn has hundreds of connections.

Reasons I'm doubting her legitimacy

1. Both the initial contact and following "opportunity" were filled
   with phrases such as "best in breed" and other filler terms.
2. It wasn't clear what product(s) the company produces
3. She didn't mention a company website
4. "Github" is listed as a technology

Currently, I've given her my email address (on linkedin) and my resume (also posted on linkedin). I'm currently trying to figure out 2 things

1. Is this some kind of scam and how does it operate?
2. Is there a way to validate this is a real recruiter with a real job?

Comment: this is 9 out of 10 recruiters. You'll be fine

Comment: This is almost every recruiter I've ever dealt with.

Answer (score 5):

Seems ok to me.

Recruiters aren't subject matter experts, so won't know what GitHub is - it sounds like a technology.

They're not going to tell you who the client is as they don't want you contacting them directly and cutting them out of their commision.

Recruiters like buzzwords and filler terms.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this some kind of scam and how does it operate?

If it's a scam, then at some point they'll ask you for money.  "Service fee." "Processing fee." "I have a great job for you but you'll need to upfront this cost."

**Legit recruiters get their money from the company.  The moment they ask you for money, walk away because there's nothing there.**

Having said that, recruiters are not normally technical people so I don't see any red flags just yet.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problems with this recruiter. If you're still suspicious, ring the main reception number of the company she works for, and ask for her by name.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds remarkably like my previous company's job posting. They describe themselves as using "best in breed" open source software and they list github as a technology.

With that in mind, I don't think it sounds fake at all. It's a legit job post and it doesn't hurt to try applying.

Comment: They may use best of breed FOSS, but do they eat their own dog food?